# jQuery scroll to function giving "Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a little trouble with a simple scroll to action I have made, I keep getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/cvLcsgm3/

JS:

```
// ordering page
    $('#order-details').hide();
    $('#order-details').on('click touchstart', function () {
        $(this).show();
        //showTarget(this.hash);
    });

    // Scroll To # Links
    $('a[href*="#"]').click(function(e) {
          //if (!$(this).hasClass('menu-button')) {
                //e.preventDefault();
                showTarget(this.hash);

                $('body').removeClass('menu-open');
          //}
    });

    $(window).load(function(e){
          showTarget(window.location.hash);
    });

    function showTarget(target) {
          target = target.replace('#', '');
          if (target) {
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.' + target).offset().top}, 700, 'swing', function() {
                      window.location.hash = '#' + target;
                });
          }
    }
```

Any ideas why I'm getting that error and how I can resolve it?

Comment: In your HTML change `<div id="order-details"></div>` to `<div class="order-details"></div>`

Comment: Perfect, thanks mate - been a long day!